# R: populate a vector incrementally

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to write a short function that assigns values and populates incrementally a vector, based on values in another vector.
For instance, if I have a vector of binaries a = [0,1,1,0,1], I want to create a vector b of the same length as a, that assigns a value x if a[1]=0, or a value y if a[1]=1. So b = [0.4,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.6]

I have done this:

```
a<-sample(0:1,20,replace=T)

    assign<-function(x){
  c<-vector()
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    ifelse (x[[i]]>0,b<-0.6,b<-0.4)
  c[[length(c)+1]]=b}
  return (b)
}
```

but then

```
assign(a)
```

only returns the first assignment. I assume I didn't nest the loop correctly?

Comment: `b <- c(0.4, 0.6)[a+1]` ?

Comment: `assign` ay ay ay.....

Comment: There's also a simple `b <- 0.2*a + 0.4`, but I think the solution by @Cath is better because it displays the two possible return values 0.4 and 0.6 in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you state that your vector `a` is binary, you can turn it into a vector of indices and use that "property":

```
bfroma <- function(x) c(0.4, 0.6)[x+1]

a <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
bfroma(a)
#[1] 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.4 0.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Some comments on your code:

1. it is not advised to do `ifelse (x[[i]] > 0, b <- 0.6, b <- 0.4)`; `ifelse` is not used as this (you'd better check `?ifelse` again). Use `b <- ifelse (x[[i]] > 0, 0.6, 0.4)`.
2. I think you want `return(c)` rather than `return(b)`;
3. use a different function name, `assign` will mask R's built-in one.

Anyway, I figured that the whole function can be replaced by

```
function (x) ifelse(x > 0, 0.6, 0.4)
```

or

```
function (x) {x <- 0.4; x[x > 0] <- 0.6; x}
```

For your **particular** case where input vector is strictly 0-1 binary, we can do better. Cath has pointed out already, by indexing only:

```
function (x) c(0.4, 0.6)[x + 1L]
```

More generally, as long as `x` is discrete, we can use `match` to get position index and use fast replacement, too, but I will not elaborate on that here.